# error while I was performing itertools i got this error : (Name Error operator not defined)

Tags: python, python-itertools

error
print(list(itertools.accumulate(li1, operator.mul)))
NameError: name 'operator' is not defined

```
import itertools
li1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
li2=[11,62,15,19,1,4,6,7,9]
li3=[10,8,6,4,5,9,8,10,5,4]
print(list(itertools.accumulate(li1, operator.mul)))
```

Comment: You need to `import operator` too.

Comment: Error seems about right. You are using word `operator` but it is not defined .what you you trying to do?

Comment: You didnot `import operator`.

Answer (score 3):

You would have forgotten to import operator.

Add the line `import operator` and your code will work fine.